# Python получить содержимое страницы

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Получаю код страницы таким скриптом, но там нет самих событий в лайве. Я так понял они динамически формируются js. Можно ли получить эти данные с помощью request? selenium использовать нехочется

```
import requests

def char_code(c):
    return c.decode('utf-8')

url = 'https://www.fonbet52.com/live/?locale=ru'
r = requests.get(url)
print(char_code(r.content))
```

Этот div пустой, а в нем должна быть линия:

```
 <!-- ЛИНИЯ -->
            <div id="lineContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Какой ужасный сайт, у меня браузер подвис на той странице о_о

Comment: А так, там много js и ajax, и само содержимое страницы подгружается по url `https://line.fbwebdn.com/live/currentLine/ru/` в виде json'а, которое после формирует html страницы. Ну и с самой страницы где-то раз в секунду уходит запрос вида `https://line.fbwebdn.com/live/updatesFromVersion/1364625609/ru/?0.47808426735620513` в котором обновления данных приходят. В запросе updatesFromVersion кст указывается следующая версия пакета. Выглядит все это громадно :)

Comment: Можете использовать какой-то движок браузера и парсить html, можете работать с запросами и с json

Comment: @gil9red оо, здорово, спасибо Вам за ссылочки. С json, думаю, будет удобнее.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под этот div пустой ? я посмотрел код если не знаете html код зачем пробуете парсить станицу ? это комментарий браузер и любые парсеры игнорируют комментарии кстати есть хорошая библиотека lxml для такой работы

Comment: Код HTML5 может браузер не поддерживает или нет стандарта

Comment: @Александр, я имею ввиду, что если посмотреть код сайта, в блоке <div id="lineContainer"></div> содержится инфа о линиях, но когда я получаю код страницы в r.content - блок пустой, линий нет.

Comment: Из всего выше изложенного я понял  что вам надо учить не Python а  JavaScript

Comment: Вы поставьте вопрос правильно что вам нужно от конкретной страницы библиотека requests прекрасно справляется с отправкой данных и получением ответа а там будете вы использовать json питона   или попытаетесь пропустить через интерпретатор JS код пришедший в  html это уже ваше дело

Comment: кстати в лайве что значит ?

Comment: @Александр от конкретной страницы мне нужно получить содержимое этого тегэ <div id="lineContainer"></div>. Библиотека request прекрасно возвращает мне пустой тэг. Ответ на мой вопрос был дан в комментарии от @ gil9red, а именно "само содержимое страницы подгружается по url https://line.fbwebdn.com/live/currentLine/ru/ в виде json'а" этот json мне и нужен был.

Comment: @Александр лайв - это спортивные события которые идут сейчас, в прямом эфире